# Validação de todas as Text box

Tags: c#

Código:

```
if (this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Text)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("É necessario preencher todos os campos.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

Esse comando foi muito útil pra mim, porem eu tenho somente 1 text pra nao preencher

Ex. Código de Cadastro

Essa text box nao sera preenchida pelo ususario, teria algum comando para deixar ela de fora?

Answer (score 0):

Adicione uma condição na sua Lambda

```
if (this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(f => f.Name != "txtCodCadastro" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Text)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("É necessario preencher todos os campos.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```